# Webpack Require SASS inside JS file?

Tags: webpack, sass

I've just been watching Jeffrey Way's intro to WebPack and one thing I can't get my head around is WHY he imports his `.scss` files into his `main.js` files only for it to be extracted again into a separate file? Why does it need to be in the JS in the first place?

Anyone kind enough to explain and help me out. I must be missing something.

Comment: Lets webpack's watcher and hot reloads work with the CSS, too, instead of needing a totally separate set of tooling to monitor those.

Comment: @ceejayoz So, should I create a main.js file with a load of requires for my CSS and other JS files? and use this as what WebPack watches?

Comment: Do it however you like. There's an infinite number of ways of setting up JavaScript builds - if you don't like Jeffrey Way's way, do something else.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm just trying to understand his way. I'm not quite sure about any other ways at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is basically, that webpack is made to build and bundle JS. There are plugins that extend webpack to provide you with SCSS, LESS, ... bundling.

Every bundle has an entrypoint. In the case of webpack, that is a .js file.
Each file that you import/require in that entry point or in a file that is imported/required in the entry point makes it into the final bundle.

The default behavior of webpack is to bundle the .scss/.css into the .js bundle as well. You can use plugins like `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` to produce a separate styles bundle.

So the answer is: webpack assumes, everything is JavaScript and you will need plugins to prove it wrong ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I actually found that you can have multiple files being passed in to it's entry point. I have passed in app.js and app.scss. Those files then import other JS or other SCSS or CSS files. Seems to be working well so far actually. Unfortunately though it is making an empty app.js file inside my css output folder. If I post the config in the OP would you take a look?